# Disable RAID auto detect at runtime

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, mdadm, fdisk

In Linux, I'm partitioning two disks for RAID1 with fdisk. The first disk partitioning succedes, but the second fail because the raid starts automatically and occupy also the second disk (why? it should have a different UUID).

How to temporary disable RAID autodetect? I guess there's a switch under `/proc/sys` filesystem.

I know it's possible to solve the problem in other ways, like removing RAID information from the disks with `mdadm --zero-superblock` but I want to know if it's possible to disable RAID autodetect without rebooting the system with `raid=noautodetect nomdadm` in kernel parameters.